# How to view sqlite database by button press

Tags: iphone, sqlite

hye all, 
i have built a SQLite database and wanna to add into iphone app. already i have add it resource->add->x.sqlite and also add libsqlite3.0.dylib.framework but i don't know what is the showing code. I wanna to show the data in the db when user pressed button. 
Can anyone help me to give an example on how the db can be view when button is press??

Comment: You are basically asking how to write programs that display data. This is far too broad to answer here.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos: Do you have a pointer to a trivial sample he could use to learn?

Answer (score 1):

Here's some basic code to query the database:

```
-(NSArray*)names
{
    NSString* query = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"SELECT name FROM sometablename;"];
    sqlite3_stmt* statement;

    int retval = sqlite3_prepare_v2(yourDatabaseHandle, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil);
    [query release];
    if (retval != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_close(yourDatabaseHandle);
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error querying table: %i", (retval ^ SQLITE_ERROR));
        return nil;
    }

    NSMutableArray* values = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        const char* value = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
        NSString* s = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:value];
        [values addObject:s];
        [s release];
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);

    return values;
}
```

You might want to present this in a table view. There are plenty of questions & answers here on Stack Overflow already to explain how to do that, as well as plenty of Apple sample code.